Illustrator place multiples files in a grid like indesign
i'v read this similar question before
How to place files on a canvas in one operation in Adobe Illustrator?
i want to place 1390 svg on a document in a grid style, whatever the format, i will later use them as symbols, i have ill v23
i've found this https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/32686120-place-multiple-files-in-a-grid-like-indesign
kelsoscript dosen't work on latest illustrator cc.
This workaround dosen't seem to work actually https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/placing-and-distributing-multiple-objects-in-illustrator/m-p/8804777
There's a script on indesign that do a similar job https://www.id-extras.com/multi-file-auto-place/
so the question stills
Or is there any external plugin that could do the job maybe?
